# Why am I having problems syncing non-itunes music to my iphone?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S with loads of music from CDs and such on my iTunes. I had an old iPod with the same account that it would all sync onto fine, however, when I try to sync it to my iPhone, nothing happens. The songs are definitely in my iTunes library. I have the settings for my iPhone to sync all songs when plugged in to the computer. Also, I have tried dragging the songs over to my iPhone where devices is shown in iTunes, and my iPhone doesn't highlight to accept songs.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your iPhone is configured to sync music from iTunes:

- Connect your iPhone to your computer
- Start iTunes
- Select you iPhone in Devices list
- Select Music tab
- Check the box Sync Music and select what you want to sync to your iPhone (all music / specific playlists)

Also make sure to "Sync only checked songs and videos" option is not checked on your iPhone Summary tab.

On your next sync (automatic or manual, depending on your settings) music should begin to sync to your iPhone.